# $2\times 2$ matrices forming the Klein $4$-group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Can someone clarify the following question:
Pick up four $2\times 2$ matrices to form the Klein $4$-group.

Comment: Find a set of four $2\times2$ matrices such that, under matrix multiplication, that group of matrices is homomorphic to the Klein-$4$ group.

Comment: @mapierce271 Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As [mapierce271 said in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100247/2-times-2-matrices-forming-the-klein-4-group/1100306#comment2243054_1100247), you are required to find a set $S$ of four $2\times 2$ matrices such that $S$, with the operation of matrix multiplication, is isomorphic to the Klein group.  The Klein group is:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
{\oplus} & e & a & b & c \\
\hline
e & e & a & b & c \\
a & a & e & c & b \\
b & b & c & e & a \\
c & c & b & a & e \\
\end{array}
$$

Obviously the matrix that corresponds to $e$ will be the identity matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]$; the trick is to find three more matrices, say $a, b, $ and $c$, with $a^2=b^2=c^2 = e$ and $ab=c$.

Answer (score 1):

What are symmetries of a rectangle? These are vertical symmetry, horizontal symmetry, $180^0$ rotation symmetry and identity. Each symmetry has order $2$ (except identity), so you see that this is actually Klein-4 group.

To arrive at matrices, consider square (which is also rectangle) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices $(1,1)$, $(1,-1)$, $(-1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. We can describe the above symmetries by matrices which you want. Let $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$.

1) The vertical symmetry (=reflection in y-axis) will take $e_1$ to $-e_1$ and $e_2$ to $e_2$, so the matrix representing this motion is $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

2) The horizontal symmetry (=reflection in x-axis) takes $e_1$ to $e_1$ and $e_2$ to $-e_2$, so in matrix form this motion is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$.

3) For $180^0$ rotation, it takes $e_1$ to $e_1$ and $e_2$ to $e_2$, so matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$.

4) For identity symmetry, the matrix is obviously identity.

These matrices give Klein-4 group.